# Dompdf - how to attasch the same pdf file into two different php file templates?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, dompdf

I need to place the same file pdf to two different templates.

But if I place the same code in both files like that, it's bugging.

If that code is in only one of that files, all works fine.

The code is

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $id, $object ) {
    $your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/pdf-test.pdf';
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path;
    return $attachments;
}

require get_template_directory() . '/pdf-test.php';
require_once get_template_directory() . '/assets/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
 use Dompdf\Dompdf;
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
 ob_start();
require(get_template_directory().'/pdf-test.php');
 $content_pdf = ob_get_clean();
 $dompdf->loadHtml( $content_pdf);
 // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
 $dompdf->setPaper('A3', 'portarait');
 // Render the HTML as PDF
 $dompdf->render();
 // Output the generated PDF to Browser 
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/pdf-test.pdf', $output);
```

The pdf-file has the same content, just has to be sent both for user and for admin.
I tried to copy the file, called it pdf-test-admin.php and pdf-test-admin.pdf, it didn't help.
I also tried to require the library in the main functions.php file, and to call only new Dompdf in files I needed, it did't work at all.
I'm still new with this library, can't find something like my task.
Plugins wouldn't help me, cause my content in php-file is very specific. I need to do it exactly on dompdf.
How to call it in two places correctly?

Comment: Do you need the contents of pdf-test.php included twice? It's in there twice which looks unusual to me.

Comment: I need to attach it in two email templates - for user and for admin, but the content in this pdf is the same

Comment: I know, but in your code, you have the line `require(get_template_directory().'/pdf-test.php');` in there twice. That could definitely throw some wrenches in if you weren't expecting the code in that file to run twice. Since I can't think of why having another file with the same code in it would make any difference, I'm looking for other things that could cause unexpected results

Comment: I have to do something like a loop? I saw examples of the loop, but for different pdf-s on the same file

Comment: I think I've found the mistake. I needed to rename action, and pdf can be the same. I'll test it few more times, but I think it is it

Comment: Oh, the function! If you're defining that same function twice it would break it for sure.

Comment: something is still broken, I search it